# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but I don't know the issue. (New to programming)

Tags: arrays

Having trouble doing my homework. Here's the objective:
Given an array of ints, return true if one of the first 4 elements in the array is a 9. The array length may be less than 4.

```
arrayFront9([1, 2, 9, 3, 4]) → true
arrayFront9([1, 2, 3, 4, 9]) → false
arrayFront9([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) → false
```

My code:

```
public boolean arrayFront9(int[] nums) {
  for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
   if(nums[i] == 9) return true;

}
return false;



}
```

Error I'm getting: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: The instructions clearly states that the array length may be less than 4 for in your for loop you will want to go up to array.length so `for(int i =0; i < nums.length; i ++)` Also, there are many other problems with your code, such as returning too early.

Comment: But what if the array is 1, 2, 3, 4, 9? It wouldn't check that only the 1st four must be 9, it will return true as long as there is a 9 regardless of if it's the 1st four or not.

Comment: Yeah but the array length might be only 3 elements and that would throw an arrayoutofboundsexception because you're trying to call the array index of 3 when it doesn't exist. or a more drastic example might be when the array length is 0. Then you're trying to get index values of an array that doesn't even hold anything.

Comment: `for(int i =0; i < nums.length && i < 4; i ++)` this should do what you want

Comment: Wow @enator! I never thought I could use the AND operator like that! Thanks. And thank you Tim Lee for telling me why I was getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're receiving the error you are is due to the size of the array you're looking at.
The question you've asked states that the array size can be less than 4, and yet your `for` statement is always expecting 4 items.

What you're after would be something like the below;

```
public boolean arrayFront9(int[] nums) {
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length && i < 4; i++){
   if(nums[i] == 9) return true;    
}
return false;
}
```

This will loop while it is smaller than the size of the array, and only through the first 4 items.

Comment: Yes, that solved it. I've never thought of using the && operator. I thought it was a lot more complicated than that!